# Using if statement in phtml

Tags: magento2.3, php, phtml

Would like to put an if statement in the below code as follows.

If saleable qty <=0 (equals 0 or under), add CSS. Otherwise, add different CSS

```
<div class="left-stock">
    <strong>
        <?= ($block->salebleqty() != '') ? $block->escapeHtml(__('Only %1 left in stock!', $block->salebleqty())) : '' ?>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code conditionally to display different CSS based on your condition:

```
<?= $block->salebleqty() <= 0 ? 'red' : 'green' ?>
```

For example:

```
<div class="left-stock">
    <?php if ($block->salebleqty() != ''): ?>
        <strong style="color:<?= $block->salebleqty() <= 0 ? 'red' : 'green' ?>">
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Only %1 left in stock!', $block->salebleqty())); ?>
        </strong>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

In this code, the `color` CSS property is added to the `strong` tag. You can adjust it to fit your needs.

---

For those using Magento 2.4.0 or higher version, it is recommended to use the `$secureRenderer` variable, which is available in the `phtml` template, to render the `style` tag. You can refer to the `image_with_borders.phtml` in Magento core for an example https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml

Comment: This works perfectly for any qty above 0 but for some reason removes the text for any qty that is 0

Comment: I've updated the example code with your original condition, the text will be displayed even if the quantity is equal to 0.

Comment: Would there be a way to also display different text based on quantity. Example qty above 0 = x amount in stock, qty below 0 = out of stock.

Comment: Use the condition: `<?php if ($block->salebleqty() > 0): ?> html code for in stock goes here. <?php else: ?>HTML code for out of stock goes here.<?php endif ?>`